# Is there a way to have a callback triggered when any new topic is created in ROS1?

Tags: ros

I'm trying to write a program in C++ that scans topics in ROS and selectively subscribes to some of them. Right now I am doing so via a timer callback, which uses `ros::master::getTopics` checks for new ones and then subscribes to them.
In general code looks very similar [to how rosbag looks for new topics](https://github.com/strawlab/ros_comm/blob/master/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp#L509-L515).

However, I was wondering if there any way to subscribe to a "topic creation event" (if it even exists) even not via standard/documented ROS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my comment for visibility: What you're looking to do is not possible in a default install of ROS1. The `roscore` registers new topics as they are created and stored internally. Because of this you would have to edit `roscore` to include a publisher for every topic that is registered.

Currently the best way to do this in incremental polling; like you're already doing.